# EJB counterpart of Spring @Profile

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of an application configuration and make it be available only in certain environments. Wanted to know whether this can be done in EJB also in any way?

Main Problem statement:

I have two different JMS infrastructure in two different environments. I want the corresponding bean to be loaded and injected.

Comment: You could use ejb-jar.xml env-entries and inject them, for example my file contains booleans with isQA, isUAT, isLab then in the code, if all those are false it goes into isProd mode, if any of them are true the code then goes into the appropriate environment mode.  If you need some examples I can provide them to you!

Comment: What the infrastructure has to do with it? All resources that bean needs (like queues, qcfactories, activespecs) should be defined by references. Then you simply map these references to actual objects in JNDI in your target environment. Or maybe I didint fully understand your requirement.

Comment: @JGlass can you please share the examples. They might help.

Comment: @Gas, suppose we had 2 different markets and one had activemq which we have to use and other didn't. I want the bean creation, injection and declaration conditionally.

Comment: Let me know if it works and if you have any problems with it!  I'll be happy to help - I use these in all my projects now as you can define qa, uat, lab and prod WSDL URL's in the ejb-jar.xml or web.xml (war project) and then the WSDL stub no longer has a hard coded URL.  And dont struggle with it too much if you have any issue - let me know, I could upload a minimal working WAR or EAR with EJB up to github and you could try it out and then integrate things yourself!

Comment: If in one env you use JMS and in other you dont, you have different application logic not just configuration. In that case you should have 2 different builds, otherwise you are packaging classes which will never be used, and also introduce unnecessary logic to calculate which class should be used.And in a few months time someone maintaining this code will not have any idea why it was done in such way and whether is still needed.

Comment: @Gas, we have two different builds deployed to two different markets for this. But the source code should be such that it allows such flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

You could use CDI alternatives and use @Inject instead of @EJB for injection
Examples:
1)if you need to specify implementation at deployment time you can use alternative

interface :

```
import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface MyserviceInterface2 {
    String doSomthing();
}
```

implementations

```
@Alternative
@Stateless
public class Interface2Impl1 implements MyserviceInterface2{
    @Override
    public String doSomthing() {
        return "Impl1";
    }
}


@Alternative
@Stateless
public class Interface2Impl2 implements MyserviceInterface2{
    @Override
    public String doSomthing() {
        return "Impl2";
    }
}
```

select your implementation in beans.xml

```
<alternatives>
    <class> [your package].Interface2Impl1</class>
</alternatives>
```

Injection point:

```
inject in client class

public class ClientClass {
    @Inject
    MyserviceInterface2 myserviceInterface2;
    ...
```

2)if you want to select implementation in runtime, you could use produces

create following qualifires

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Impl1Qulifier {
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Impl2Qulifier {
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface SelectedImpQulifier {
}
```

interface:

```
@Local
public interface MyServiceInterface {
    String doSomthing();
}
```

implementations :

```
@Impl1Qulifier
@Stateless
public class MyServiceImpl1 implements MyServiceInterface{
    @Override
    public String doSomthing() {
        return "Impl1";
    }
}

@Impl2Qulifier
@Stateless
public class MyServiceImpl2 implements MyServiceInterface{
    @Override
    public String doSomthing() {
        return "impl2";
    }
}
```

produces:

```
public class ImplProvider {
    @Inject @Impl1Qulifier
    MyServiceInterface impl1;

    @Inject @Impl2Qulifier
    MyServiceInterface imp2;

    @Produces @SelectedImpQulifier
    MyServiceInterface createServiceInterface(InjectionPoint injectionPoint ) {
//        if( your conditions ){
//            return impl1
//        }
        return imp2;
    }
}
```

injection point:

```
public class ClientClass {
    @Inject @SelectedImpQulifier
    MyServiceInterface myServiceInterface;
    ...
```

you also could use JNDI lookup for second situation

You also could put each implementation in different  module(jar) and use the proper one for each environment in ear that is created for that environment (doing proper assembling for each of them)

Comment: What I need is to inject conditionally depending on some system configuration

Comment: Cdi producer or jndi lookup(in a factory) could help if you need select implementation runtime. As I know spring profile setting is done in application config like alternative that is done in module config

Comment: an example would be really helpful.

Comment: I've added examples to the post

Answer (score 1):

**Using env-entry's in your EJB project for environment configuration**

**Example** ejb-jar.xml (this is placed in the "META-INF" folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_2.xsd" version="3.2">
<display-name>MSInterceptorMDBSimpleOrderHandler </display-name>

<enterprise-beans>
<message-driven>
    <ejb-name>InterceptorMDBSimpleOrderHandler</ejb-name>
    <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>

    <env-entry>
        <description>Variables to distinguish between prod, uat and qa environments</description>
        <env-entry-name>isQA</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.Boolean</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>false</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>

    <env-entry>
        <description>Variables to distinguish between prod, uat and qa environments</description>
        <env-entry-name>isUAT</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.Boolean</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>false</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>

    <!-- Not QA or UAT means it's prod -->

    <env-entry>
        <description>Variable to distinguish between linux and windows for file access</description>
        <env-entry-name>isLinux</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.Boolean</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>true</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>

    <env-entry>
        <description>Variable to use as linux folder path file access</description>
        <env-entry-name>linuxPath</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>/home/jboss/XML_JMS_Responses</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>

    <env-entry>
        <description>Variable to use as windows folder path file access</description>
        <env-entry-name>windowsPath</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>C:\\local_git_repo\\PSD_Interceptor\\XML_JMS_Responses</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>        
</message-driven>
```

**Example code** (note, this is a MDB):

```
@MessageDriven
public class InterceptorMDBSimpleOrderHandler implements MessageListener {
        @Resource(name="isQA")
        boolean isQA;
        @Resource(name="isUAT")
        boolean isUAT;
        @Resource(name="isLinux")
        boolean isLinux;
        @Resource(name="linuxPath")
        String linuxPath;
        @Resource(name="windowsPath")
        String windowsPath;

        //other vars modified by resource injected values
        String path = "";
        boolean isWindows = false;
        boolean isProd = false;

        @PostConstruct
        public void initialize() {
            LOGGER.info("InterceptorMDBSimpleOrderHandler:->PostConstruct:->initialize");

            if(!isQA && !isUAT){
                isProd = true;
            }

            if(!isLinux){
                isWindows = true;
                path = windowsPath;
            }else{
                path = linuxPath;
            }

            LOGGER.info("InterceptorMDBSimpleOrderHandler Constructed with following settings:");
            LOGGER.info("isQA: " + isQA);
            LOGGER.info("isUAT: " + isUAT);
            LOGGER.info("isProd: " + isProd);
            LOGGER.info("isLinux: " + isLinux);
            LOGGER.info("isWindows: " + isWindows);
            LOGGER.info("linuxPath: " + linuxPath);
            LOGGER.info("windowsPath: " + windowsPath);
            LOGGER.info("Path to use: " + path);

            //this is where you'd call a method or whatever that cares 
            //about the environment settings.

            LOGGER.info("InterceptorMDBSimpleOrderHandler:->PostConstruct:->Finish initialized");
        }

}
```

It doesnt need to be a message driven bean, it can be just a EJB in which case you'd change "message-driven" to "session" in the ejb-jar.xml as such:

```
<enterprise-beans>
<session>
  <ejb-name>Configuration</ejb-name>
  <init-on-startup>true</init-on-startup>
  <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
```

The above is a snippet from an EJB class called "Configuration" which holds a whole bunch of env-entries related to configuration for the app.

For more information [ENC Usage Conventions Environment_Entries](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/ENC_Usage_Conventions-Environment_Entries.html) it's a little old but 80% or more still holds true.

Comment: Sorry, my question might be dumb as I am new to EJB. In case of Beans (Class Objects) they do not have default values and the objects are null if we are unable to wire them, but boolean has a default value, will that scenario be a little different.

Comment: That is true - but for my needs, e.g. lab, qa and uat boolean vars - if deploying to lab, qa or uat I just set one to true so if all are false it ends up being prod.  Ditto with the isLinux setting which helps tremendously when I develop locally on windows and then deploy to linux (note though to solve that I started including apache lang library I believe which has a means of detecting though OS).  If you dont want to use bools... you could always do the env-entry as a string, so it could be "uat", "qa", "lab" or "prod" and then you programatically determine what env entries to use